# Tkinter: How to disable a button after it is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to make hangman in python using Tkinter and I have mostly finished the game but, I want to add a feature that disables the button once it is pressed so that the user doesn't guess the same letter twice. Any idea how I can implement it.

the code:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0tjlSZC_xHCQ0WopNPRJC1pLNaQ4wRR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Disabling buttons is covered in the Button widget documentation. If you tried something based on that documentation and it's not working, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Please include code related to your question **in your question**.

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you overwrite the `button` object when you create all the buttons, the `button` object will also be `None` because `place()` doesn't return anything.
Split that line in two:

```
button = Button(...) and
button.place(...)
```

But even then the button object is overwritten for each new button, so the button object takes the value of the last button 'z'.

To disable individual buttons, you need to be able to access each of them, e.g. by putting all objects in a list: `button[n] = Button(...)` Then in the `guess()` function you must disable exactly that button that was pressed.